# Using leapfrog method to solve system of ODE's

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a particular system using NDsolve and specifically the leapfrog method. I have gotten NDsolve to work using NDsolve withoiut specifying a method. I tried reading the documentation on splitting methods for NDsolve but it seems I don't understand enough of it.

From my understanding `NDSolve` does not have a leapfrog option so we have to "code" it in using the existing options like what is done here:https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSplitting.html

This is my code, which doesn't work (errors `NDSolve::spltdim`, `NDSolve::initf`):

```
c1 = 3
k1 = -1
w = 1
x0 = -0.1
y0 = 0
u = 0
H = -0.1
v = 0.681507026554037
eq1 = x''[t] == (0.5 k1) ((((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^2 + 
          2 (c1) (x[t]^2 - y[t]^2) + (c1^2))^(-1.5)) (4 (x[t]^2 + 
           y[t]^2) x[t] + 4 x[t] (c1))) + 2 w y'[t]
eq2 = y''[t] == (0.5 k1) ((((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^2 + 
          2 (c1) (x[t]^2 - y[t]^2) + (c1^2))^(-1.5)) (4 (x[t]^2 + 
           y[t]^2) y[t] - 4 y[t] (c1))) - 2 w x'[t]
sol1 = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, x'[0] == u, 
   y'[0] == v}, {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 120}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 1/10, 
  Method -> {"Splitting", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, 
    "Equations" -> {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]}, 
    "Method" -> {"ExplicitEuler"}}]
```

The following doesn't work either (errors `NDSolve::sprkpqv`, `NDSolve::initf`):

```
SymplecticLeapfrog = {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" :> qvars}; time = {t, 0,
   120};
qvars = {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]};
sol1 = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, x'[0] == u, 
     y'[0] == v}, {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 120}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 1/10, 
    Method -> SymplecticLeapfrog]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274544/1871

Comment: From your link `SymplecticLeapfrog = {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" :> qvars};`. Another options is [NDSolvePlugIns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)

Comment: @I.M. trying it out this way still seems to not work, I have included the edited code

Comment: Syntax error: `qvars = {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]};`. It would also be nice if semicolons where at the ends of the parameter assignments. Their output is unnecessary.

Comment: Note that for the method "Splitting", the documentation seems to imply the problem must be cast in a first-order autonomous form $u'=F(u)$, where $u$ would be the vector $(x,y,x',y')$ in this case. OTOH "Splitting" does not complain about second-order ODEs, which leaves open the possibility that it does handle higher-order equations. But I think not....

Comment: Further, to apply a symplectic method, not only does the vector field have to split, it has to be separable. But your system is not separable. For instance $(x',y',x'',y'')=F(x,y,x',y') = A(x,y)+B(x',y')$ with the $x'',y''$ components of (,) being zero and the $x',y'$ components of $B(x',y')$ being zero. Here the `qvars` are `{x, y}` and the p variables are `{x', y'}`. (Note: I'm writing `x'` and `y'`, but when the system is converted to first-order, I'd give them new variables, say `xp` for `x'` and `yp` for `y'` -- or whatever names you like).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does this mean that since my potential is non-seperable, I cannoit use this method?

Comment: Right, as far as I know, separability is a requirement for symplectic methods like leapfrog.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks alot for your help!